# question about finite extension

Tags: field-theory

Gives  an  example  of  an algebraics  extension  which is  not a  finite extension ?

My attempt : i know that if  $K$  be  an extesnsion  of  a field $\mathbb{F}$. An  element $a \in K$ is algebraics over $\mathbb{F}$ if  and only  if $[ F(a) :F]$ is  finite

But  here  i don't know  how can i find an algebraic extension

Any hints/solution will be aprreciated

thanks u

Comment: Duplicate of (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455932/counter-example-any-algebraic-extension-is-finite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about
$$\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,2^{1/3},2^{1/4},\ldots)?$$
This contains $\Bbb Q(2^{1/n})$ which has degree $n$ over $\Bbb Q$ (Eisenstein).

Comment: im little bit confused  @Lord shark....here  polynomial  is degree n..that  mean  it is  finite..im not  getting  how  it is infinite